# Error message display on screen : The driver executable does not exist: /Project/Driver/chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error and unable to find solution of this issue, I am working with MAC, and same proper working in Windows.

when I calling browser then error message display on sceen.
This is my code.

```
package Testmavenproject.Project;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Project/Driver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.qr-code-generator.com/");

    }

}
```

Getting error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver
>   executable does not exist: /Project/Driver/chromedriver   at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:137)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:132)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:156)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:346)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:91)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>     at Testmavenproject.Project.Testing.main(Testing.java:11)

Comment: Please correct your path and provide absolute path.. not a relative one. It should be something like `/Users/<your_username>/path_to_chromedriver`. You can right click on the chromedriver executable and find the path in there.

Comment: @demouser123 bro same issue after adding absolute path 

public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/saurabh.gupta/eclipse-workspace/Project/Driver/chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.qr-code-generator.com/");

 }

Comment: Also, `.exe` doesn't work on Macintosh machines. You need to change the permissions too using `chmod`.

Comment: @demouser123 can you plz let me know how to change then permission too using chmod

Thanks,

Comment: Google will be your guide. It's a fairly common procedure/command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mac, then ".exe" doesn't work. Make sure you have chromedriver for mac. It should be "chromedriver" without .exe